# How to change Drupal 7 theme while getting HTTP Error 500

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-themes

This is with Drupal 7x. I loaded my theme on Drupal.  It has produced a HTTP ERROR 500.  That is all that appears on my browser window, that is.  Now I can not even get to the login pate to log on to the dashboard to fix this or even uninstall the theme.  Please help.  For now I would not mind too much if I could just set things back to the way they were before I made the Porto theme my default theme.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [drush](https://docs.drush.org/en/7.x/install/) to set the theme back to one that works with:

```
drush vset theme_default name_of_working_theme
```

to set the backend theme:

```
drush vset admin_theme name_of_working_theme
```